# Clustering with longitude and latitude with python

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dataset with longitude and latitude information and I need a way to cluster my data if the distance between observations is less than 300m. Anyone has any idea? I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
mydata=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Gooljarsd\\Downloads\\restaurantes.csv")
bogota=mydata[(mydata['CITY']=="Bogota")]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage

X=bogota[['LAT','LNG']].values
print(X)

Z = linkage(X,
            method='ward',
            metric='euclidean'
    )
```

but I got this error:

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 4.56 GiB for an array with shape (611852671,) and data type float64

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code critically depends on a file local to your computer, and you omitted the latter part of the error message (traceback), so we have no idea *where* the error occurred.

Comment: The root problem is that you tried to allocate an array larger than your available memory.  Since you haven't explained just what a "cluster" is for you, we can't help you work around the problem.  Without that goal, there's no way to suggest a path to the goal.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a KDTree and then return the indices of points within a certain distance and it should definitely help with your memory issues:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tree_data = my_data[['LAT', 'LNG']]
tree = KDTree(tree_data, metric='haversine')

bogota = my_data.loc[(my_data.CITY == 'Bogota'), ['LAT', 'LNG']]
idx, dist = tree.query_radius(X=bogota, r=300, return_distance=True)
```

There are plenty of other methods you can use, for example `query()` will return n nearest neighbours, so it will be essentially a KNN but with less memory use.

**EDIT:**
Since your data is in lat and long form, the standard Euclidean metric won't work and Haversine metric should be used instead. See other valid metrics here:
[enter link description here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html)